# condition checking overflows over multiplication

Tags: overflow, conditional-statements

`(A*B)>0` condition cannot be checked if A & B are large.
How to find check this condition for `(A,B)` lies between `-2147483648` to `2147483647`

provided the solution is optimal

Comment: Your range (between -2147483648 to -2147483647) is rather small. Only two numbers belong to it. For numbers within that range, the expression `(A*B)>0` can be simplified to just `true`. All of the four multiplications you can do with these two numbers give a positive result.

Comment: I refuse to give an answer to this question, because it shows no research effort, so I will copy my previous answer into a comment: Check the equivalent expression `((A > 0) && (B > 0)) || ((A < 0) && (B < 0))`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply divide the result by one of the operands (unless that is zero), and check whether the result of the division is the other operand.